# Chrome 1px unavoidable Spacing between td

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, border

I'm having a problem that appears to only occur in Chrome and nowhere else. I have a table, which has a style applied to it on hover. In other browsers, the style is applied when hovering over any part of the row. However, in chrome, at the edge of each td, the style is no longer applied. If I "inspect element" on this small 1px wide area between cells, the elements pane shows that Chrome thinks I am within the table, but not within the row itself. Here is some code which produces this effect:

CSS:

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr:hover {
    background: #8dbdd8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Title1</th> 
                <th>Title2</th> 
                <th>Title3</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>
            <tr> 
                <td>Bach</td> 
                <td>42526</td> 
                <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Doe</td> 
                <td>243155</td> 
                <td>Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AM</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>Conway</td> 
                <td>35263</td>
                <td>Jan 18, 2001 9:12 AM</td> 
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>
```

Anybody seen this before / know a way around it?

If it helps, I am using Chrome 13.0.782.220.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yNPtU/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing :hover status on <tr> between <td>'s in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10638935/1015609)

Comment: Have the same issue, no resolutions, except dirty -1px positionting. It's actually 0.5px, not 1px.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly this is not caused by the border. If you set a border width to 10px, there is still only 1px in-between the cells that causes this.

I tried setting the position of the tds which seemed to work. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lnrb0b/6harr/

**Note:** I've added the padding in to keep the size consistent

Comment: +1 since its a possible solution. But maybe has some negative impact on other browsers and for sure has some negative impact on rendering performance because of position relative calculation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638819), this will solve it:

```
td {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position:relative;
}
```

And the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2Sgqy/4/).

Answer (score -1):

The table has cellpadding and cellspacing by default. You will need to add:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Answer (score -3):

Give **border-spacing:-1px** in css.