# Losing :hover status on <tr> between <td>'s in Chrome

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to achieve a simple table row hover effect by changing the background colour of a row when a users hovers overs over it, that was simple enough:

```
tr:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

However I have noticed a bug in chrome where there is a small space between cells in a row where I lose the `:hover` and the `<tr>` flicks the style on/off as you move over it even though my mouse is still on the row.

I've tried `border-collapse: collapse`, `cellspacing="0"` but cannot see why I am losing the `<tr>` hover between cells, it only happens either side of cells, not above/below them. It works as expected in Firefox.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Sgqy/3/), in Chrome, try to slowly move your mouse from 'first' to 'second' and you will see there is a very thin point between them where the `<tr>` loses it's hover background.

I have reported this as a Chromium bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128552).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why this works, but setting the positioning on the `<td>` elements seems to fix this in Chrome.

```
td {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2Sgqy/4/)**.

Comment: That's bizarre and doesn't seem to have any side effects, thanks.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz - I agree. I haven't found any reason for this yet other than it may be a Chrome bug.

Comment: I have reported it here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128552

Comment: Weird  Solution, but I am SO glad you found it! The funny part is, the problem was only there when I accessed the page from the server. On the same Chrome, one the same computer, side by side, the local version did not generate the space.